# Change loadings (arrows) length in PCA plot using ggplot2/ggfortify?

Tags: r, ggplot2, pca, ggfortify

I have been struggling with rescaling the loadings (arrows) length in a ggplot2/ggfortify PCA.  I have looked around extensively for an answer to this, and the only information I have found either code new biplot functions or refer to other entirely different packages for PCA (ggbiplot, factoextra), neither of which address the question I would like to answer:

Is it possible to scale/change size of PCA loadings in ggfortify?

Below is the code I have to plot a PCA using stock R functions as well as the code to plot a PCA using autoplot/ggfortify.  You'll notice in the stock R plots I can scale the loads by simply multiplying by a scalar (*20 here) so my arrows aren't cramped in the middle of the PCA plot.  Using autoplot...not so much.  What am I missing?  I'll move to another package if necessary but would really like to have a better understanding of ggfortify.

On other sites I have found, the graph axes limits never seem to exceed +/- 2.  My graph goes +/- 20, and the loadings sit staunchly near 0, presumably at the same scale as graphs with smaller axes.  I would still like to plot PCA using ggplot2, but if ggfortify won't do it then I need to find another package that will.

```
#load data geology rocks frame
georoc <- read.csv("http://people.ucsc.edu/~mclapham/earth125/data/georoc.csv")

#load libraries
library(ggplot2)
library(ggfortify)

geo.na <- na.omit(georoc) #remove NA values
geo_matrix <- as.matrix(geo.na[,3:29]) #create matrix of continuous data in data frame
pca.res <- prcomp(geo_matrix, scale = T) #perform PCA using correlation matrix (scale = T)
summary(pca.res) #return summary of PCA

#plotting in stock R
plot(pca.res$x, col = c("salmon","olivedrab","cadetblue3","purple")[geo.na$rock.type], pch = 16, cex = 0.2)
#make legend
legend("topleft", c("Andesite","Basalt","Dacite","Rhyolite"), 
       col = c("salmon","olivedrab","cadetblue3","purple"), pch = 16, bty = "n")
#add loadings and text
arrows(0, 0, pca.res$rotation[,1]*20, pca.res$rotation[,2]*20, length = 0.1)
text(pca.res$rotation[,1]*22, pca.res$rotation[,2]*22, rownames(pca.res$rotation), cex = 0.7)

#plotting PCA
autoplot(pca.res, data = geo.na, colour = "rock.type", #plot results, name using original data frame
         loadings = T, loadings.colour =  "black", loadings.label = T,
         loadings.label.colour = "black")
```

The data comes from an online file from a class I'm taking, so you could just copy this if you have the ggplot2 and ggfortify packages installed.  Graphs below.

[R plot of what I want ggplot to look like](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QcbXQ.png)

[What ggplot actually looks like](https://i.stack.imgur.com/n39Hn.png)

Edit:
Adding reproducible code below.

```
iris.res <- 
  iris %>% 
  select(Sepal.Length:Petal.Width) %>% 
  as.matrix(.) %>% 
  prcomp(., scale = F)

autoplot(iris.res, data = iris, size = 4, col = "Species", shape = "Species", 
         x = 1, y = 2, #components 1 and 2
         loadings = T, loadings.colour = "grey50", loadings.label = T, 
         loadings.label.colour = "grey50", loadings.label.repel = T) + #loadings are arrows
  geom_vline(xintercept = 0, lty = 2) +
  geom_hline(yintercept = 0, lty = 2) +
  theme(aspect.ratio = 1) +
  theme_bw()
```

Comment: Your link to csv does not exist so I couldn't reproduce it. However, by looking at your result, it seems like your text labels are very messy so I'd suggest installing `ggrepel` package and then run your code again.

Comment: Also, you can pass additional arguments in `autoplot` which will get passed to `ggbiplot` in `ggfortify`. Take a look at `?ggbiplot` to see if you can find any arguments you need, e.g. `loadings.label.size`.

Comment: Sorry about the link, it seems the coarse was chnaged and so were the URLs. Thanks for the tip!

Comment: @YuanTang Hi, thanks for your tip! However, there still not solutions for changing the arrow size and the line width of the loadings with `ggfortify`.

Comment: @pengchy The answer might just be no. There is a scale function for autoplot, but it scales the entire plot by a chosen factor rather than just the arrow tips.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This answer is probably long after the OP needs it, but I'm offering it because I have been wrestling with the same issue for a while, and maybe I can save someone else the same effort.

```
# Load data
iris <- data.frame(iris)

# Do PCA
PCA <- prcomp(iris[,1:4])

# Extract PC axes for plotting
PCAvalues <- data.frame(Species = iris$Species, PCA$x)

# Extract loadings of the variables
PCAloadings <- data.frame(Variables = rownames(PCA$rotation), PCA$rotation)

    # Plot
ggplot(PCAvalues, aes(x = PC1, y = PC2, colour = Species)) +
  geom_segment(data = PCAloadings, aes(x = 0, y = 0, xend = (PC1*5),
     yend = (PC2*5)), arrow = arrow(length = unit(1/2, "picas")),
     color = "black") +
  geom_point(size = 3) +
  annotate("text", x = (PCAloadings$PC1*5), y = (PCAloadings$PC2*5),
     label = PCAloadings$Variables)
```

[image]

In order to increase the arrow length, multiply the loadings for the `xend` and `yend` in the `geom_segment` call. With a bit of trial and effort, can work out what number to use.

To place the labels in the correct place, multiply the PC axes by the same value in the `annotate` call.

Comment: Good tip. In the end I opted to keep the PCAs in base plot. Not my preferred plotting method, but it turned out to work well (especially for NMDS). However I will file this for future use.